# Next.js & googleapi: Array of arrays without keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-api, next.js

I'm new to next.js, in the `getStaticProps` function I'm loading a googlesheet table into a constant. The result is an array of arrays, here's an example of the googleapi return:

```json
[
   [
      "CLIENT A",
      "MIKE",
      "UNKNOWN",
      "TRADICIONAL"
   ],
   [
      "CLIENT B",
      "MARY",
      "UNKNOWN",
      "MOROSO"
   ],
   [
      "CLIENT C",
      "MIKE",
      "CLIENT C S.A DE C.V.",
      "TRADICIONAL"
   ],
   [
      "CLIENT D",
      "JOHN",
      "RAZON SOCIAL CLIENT",
      "TRADICIONAL"
   ]
]
```

I'm returning this array as props, but I can't find a way to manipulate the information so I can display it like:

CLIENT A
Salesperson: MIKE
Razón Social: UNKNOWN 
Category: TRADICIONAL

--------------------
CLIENT B
Salesperson: MARY
Razón Social: UNKNOWN 
Category: MOROSO

--------------------
CLIENT C
Salesperson: MIKE
Razón Social: CLIENT C S.A DE C.V. 
Category: MOROSO

I was trying to find a way to add keys to the array, but I can't find how to do it and have something like:

```json
{
    client: "CLIENT A",
    salesperson: "MIKE",
    razonsocial: "UNKNOWN",
    category: "TRADICIONAL",
}
```

I also tried to map the array of arrays but I get an error message saying that I can't map it.

Can somebody please help me suggesting me how is the best way to deal with the array?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're after?

```js
const data = [
  ["CLIENT A", "MIKE", "UNKNOWN", "TRADICIONAL"],
  ["CLIENT B", "MARY", "UNKNOWN", "MOROSO"],
  ["CLIENT C", "MIKE", "CLIENT C S.A DE C.V.", "TRADICIONAL"],
  ["CLIENT D", "JOHN", "RAZON SOCIAL CLIENT", "TRADICIONAL"]
];
const keys = ['', 'Salesperson', 'Razón Social', 'Category'];
data.map(d => {
  d.forEach((e, i) => {
    console.log(`${keys[i]?keys[i]+": ":''}${e}`)
  })
  console.log('------------------');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

No exactly, what I'm trying to do is to have the data array return as props to my default function. The problem is that I cannot map the renglon object and also can't add keys to renglon object. Here's my code in the function home the client.name doesn't work and because can't create the key, also can't use client[0].

```js
import { google } from 'googleapis';

export async function getStaticProps() {
  
    const auth = await google.auth.getClient({ scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly'] });

    const sheets = google.sheets({ version: 'v4', auth });
    const range = `Sheet!A$2:D`;

    const response = await sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
        spreadsheetId: process.env.SHEET_ID,
        range,
    });

    // I want to add keys to renglon, but can't find how
    const renglon = response.data.values;
    
    if (renglon.length) {
      return {
        props: {
          renglon,
        }
      };
    }

}

export default function Home( { renglon } ) {
    return (
      <div className="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 gap-4">
        {renglon.map((client) => {
         return (
            <li>Client: {client.name}</li>  //Can't create this key or use client[0]
            Sales person: {client.salesperson}<br />//Can't create this key or use client[1]
            Razón Social: {client.razonsocial}<br />//Can't create this key or use client[2]
            Category: {client.category}<br /> //Can't create this key or use client[3]
         )
       })}
      </div>
    );
}
```